# Custom UITableViewCell loaded from StoryBoard not getting dealloc'ed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

Here's my code:

```
__weak CurrentViewController *weakSelf = self;
if (indexPath.row == 0) //Name Cell
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NameCell";
    NameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    __weak NameCell *weakCell = cell;
    cell.NameDidChangeBlock = ^(){
        weakSelf.zoneName = weakCell.NameTextField.text;
    };

    return cell;
}
else if (indexPath.row == 1) //Number Cell
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NumberCell";        
    NumberCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.someBlock = ^(){
        [weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };

    return cell;
}
```

Neither "NameCell" nor "NumberCell" dealloc method is getting called.
I have both these custom cells designed and put up as top level objects in CurrentViewController's storyboard.

CurrentViewController's dealloc is getting called, but custom cell's dealloc's aren't. 
I see in the Instruments that the retainCount of the custom cells increases each time creating an instance of CurrentViewController.

Here are my headers of Custom cells:

```
//NameCell.h:
@property(nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet UITextField *NameTextField;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NameDidChange NameDidChangeBlock;

//NumberCell.h
@property(nonatomic, weak)Manager *manager;
@property(nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet AKPickerView *pickerView;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *numbersArray;
@property(nonatomic)int selectedZoneNumber;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *selectionBoxView;
@property (nonatomic, copy)some someBlock;
```

Any help here would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
My tableView itself is not getting dealloc'ed after CurrentViewController gets dealloc'ed.
Tried to log through a UITableView category.
Still, guessing, why would my tableView wont get released when my viewController is already released. Seems too weird.

Comment: When you checked if the cells were deallocated? Cells are owned by tableView which could reuse the cells so it will not deallocate them. The tableView is owned by the controller's view (parent) and all objects will be deallocated when the view controller gets deallocated.

Comment: Answering @LucianBoboc: Even after CurrentViewController gets dealloc'ed, i see the cells aren't dealloc'ed (in the Instruments [ Allocations tool ] ).
Also, "dealloc" method in the custom cells aren't getting called.

These methods are for "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method.

Comment: The cells blocks looks fine, weak vars are used.

Comment: Answering @hasan83: Yes, am using ARC and i set out nil to all strong objects.

Comment: since you are using ARC you don't have to set nil for strong object. right? but, I can't tell yet what is your problem.

Comment: Am using iPhone6- iOS8.3

Comment: can you upload your project to github?

Comment: Sorry, that would be impractical, as this comes from a big piece of code. 
Else, may be i'll have to put it separately and try it out & share that piece with u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Culprit was this Guy: [ShowKit](https://www.showkit.com/)

We had ShowKit Integrated into our App for Remote Support.

Removing their SDK from our App did solve the above mentioned dealloc Issue (Not just the above, but there were more issues than we thought).

I think ShowKit SDK does takes a copy of our App's views and doesn't return it back and may be the retain count of the copied views doesn't goes to 0 at all.

OR

May be the SDK has an handle over my App's UIWindow and they aren't releasing it when not needed.

That's purely my guess, not sure though. They'll have to answer it.

I hope someone finds this helpful.